# Opt out certain file extensions from Optimize Imports

Tags: intellij-idea

**Problem**

IntelliJ IDEA's optimize imports appears to remove namespaces in xjb binding files files that it detects as unused. However this breaks some of our xjb binding files as they are actually used.

I found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126416, but adding the suppress statement is not a viable solution for us.

**Question**

Is it possible to opt out certain file extensions (here *.xjb) from the optimize imports functionality?

Comment: I have the same question, would be really useful!